# Error while starting newly installed Hive/Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I just installed CDH 5.4. I am getting below message when I start the Hive.

Message from Cloudera Manager:

```
Canary test failed to create file in directory /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files.
```

message from server:

Caused by:
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/hdfs/5502ca90-629f-4c7e-afd5-dada9535d15c. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 404 needs additional 504 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 908.
The number of live datanodes 3 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.

How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Reason is :
A Safemode for Namenode is essentially a read-only mode for the HDFS cluster, where it does not allow any modifications to filesystem or blocks. 
Normally Namenode gets out of safemode automatically at the beginning. If required, HDFS could be placed in safemode explicitly using 'bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode' command. Namenode front page shows whether safemode is on or off.

Try the same after SafeMode exit.

If Still SafeMode takes more than Normal Time, execute

> hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

If says permission issue thn use **hdfs** user to perform the same then check the Hive status.

Comment: thanks, even when I tun safemode OFF, it gets ON in few minutes. Not sure what is causing it. Also it shows block size 286572 B, whereas in Cloudera Manager it shows 128 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the NameNode out of the Safe Mode.

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```